How to debug "Content-Security-Policy (CSP)" and nonces in NextJS
I am trying to setup the CSP header in my NextJS app (App router).
I added the "Content Security Policy" Security Header, specifically the "src-script" directive. BUT I am getting an error, basically saying that there is some unknown script host (besides the ones listed) that is violating this directive. Chrome isn't helpful in that it doesn't know WHICH script is violating this.
Problem
How do I identify all the src-script sources in my app, without having to pore through the codebase?
vercel.json snippet:
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Content-Security-Policy",
          "value": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' *.posthog.com; style-src 'self';"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Error
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src" 'self' https://.posthog.com".*

Can you share the full and exact error message?

Edited to include Error msg! @NicoHaase

As usual: share all details in text form, not hidden in screenshots. Also, did you allow inline scripts (which you should not use) anywhere, as proposed in the error message?

@NicoHaase thx for the heads up, replaced with text error. No, i have not allowed inline scripts anywhere.

If you haven't allowed inline scripts yet, but the error message tells you the browser found any, you have two options: refactor them (such that you don't use any of them), or allow their usage

@NicoHaase ty for the answer. I guess the question was, how do I check which scripts are being used, without having to check the entire codebase? Or is there a keyword I could be searching for, like 'src' or ''?

Please add all such clarification to your question by editing it. Something like <script> might already be a good starting point

OK I figured it out. There were several issues. SUPER annoying that nextjs docs don't make these explicit.
My original attempt was to add CSP as part of vercel.json, but you should set it in middleware instead.
Annoying nextjs landmine #1. Nonces get automagically added to your next scripts in prod, once you set them up.
After following this doc and adding the CSP middleware, it wasn't clear how the damn nonce's were getting added to the _next script tags. Answer: They just automagically get added!! (in dev it just says <script nonce> - very hard to tell if the nonce value is getting applied).
Annoying nextjs landmine #2. You have to make your root layout.tsx to dynamic.
Thanks to this answer I was able to answer this one. Again, the NextJS docs on this are confusing. Yes, I know, it does explicitly say:

Every time a page is viewed, a fresh nonce should be generated. This means that you must use dynamic rendering to add nonces.

But as someone who's not so familiar with Nextjs, it would've been nice if the example spelled it out. Something like "to use dynamic rendering, add this to your root layout.tsx file: export const dynamic = "force-dynamic""
3. Your CSP contents need to be dynamic based on your dev/prod environment.
If you're in dev, you need it to be unsafe-eval otherwise it won't work locally. Here's my CSP string:
  const cspHeader = `
    default-src 'self';
    connect-src 'self' some.domain.com another.domain.com *.example.com ${isDev ? `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}` : ''};
    script-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' 'strict-dynamic' ${isDev ? "'unsafe-eval'" : ''};
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src 'self' blob: data: some.domain.com;
    font-src 'self';
    object-src 'none';
    base-uri 'self';
    form-action 'self';
    frame-ancestors 'none';
    upgrade-insecure-requests;
`

Where NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL is localhost:8000 or whatever your backend URL is.
4. Whenever you integrate a new domain into your app, you need to include them in the connect-src directive, not script-src. This took a lot of experimenting, but I got there. #3 above for examples.
For example, if you're loading posthog into your app, it should be:
connect-src 'self' *.posthog.com;

Other helpful links: here

thank you very much.  wasted way too much time trying to solve other ways and this fixed it all for me.
